# Yum issues after upgrading MySQL from 5.0 to 5.5 on RHEL

Tags: mysql, redhat, yum, package-management

I'm running `RHEL 5.6` and trying to upgrade `MySQL` from `5.0` to `5.5`. I ran `sudo yum remove mysql*` to remove all the existing `MySQL`-related packages.

Then I installed `MySQL` `5.5` packages:

```
$ sudo yum install mysql55*
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, rhnplugin, security
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package mysql55-embedded-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-server-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-test-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-devel-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-bench-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-embedded-devel-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-libs-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql55-debuginfo-5.5.22-1.ius.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

When I check the list of packages it tells me I still have `5.0`:

```
$ sudo yum list mysql
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, rhnplugin, security
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Available Packages
mysql.i386                             5.0.77-4.el5_6.6                           rhel-x86_64-server-5.6.z
mysql.x86_64                           5.0.77-4.el5_6.6                           rhel-x86_64-server-5.6.z
```

But when I check the `MySQL` `client` and `server` I do seem to be running `5.5`:

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

$ tail /var/log/mysqld.log
Version: '5.5.22-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Distributed by The IUS Community Project
```

**Q: How can I fix yum to properly reflect the newly installed packages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sudo yum list mysql` is showing those mysql packages as *Available*, not installed.  How about checking the output of `yum list installed 'mysql*'`

Comment: Please vote up that comment if you think my question should be removed as it's a big miss from myself rather than any problem other people could be running into.